# ngRoute with restful path

Tags: angularjs

My app sits on `example.com/app`, for example. As you can see I have a certain word located just after "/". Now I want to show some content when navigating to "#profile" implementing single page application approach by clicking on:

```
<a href="#profile">Go to profile</a>
```

So, how it is correct to define route for `when()` procedures?

```
when( "/app/profile", {...}) // does not work
when( "/app#profile", {...}) // does not work also
when( "/app/#profile", {...}) // does not work
```

Kind of confused..

Comment: Try to add a `<base href="http://example.com/app" />` in your `<head />`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base. Then, remove `/app` from your mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should properly configure application [base URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) - it will be the path all resource requests to resolve relative to. In your case it will be:

```
<base href="http://example.com/app" />
```

or better to make it domain agnostic like this:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

Then you will define all your routes relative to this base:

```
when("/profile", {
    controller:  'profileController',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when( "/profile", {...}) // use it this way it should work
```

More info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)